# Tabs without call facility capturing unique device id

Tags: cordova

I am working on Apache Cordova (Hybrid) based project where we are planning to capture the details such as IMEI number of the device . This work's fine when we are running the application in Mobile device . We would like to capture the same on Tab . I agree that tab do not have IMEI number (no calling facility) . Is there any other stander number/id we can capture for tab's .

Thought of capturing UUID but the issue is I am unable to find the Id on the device settings. So some of the thread suggested to download application which would help us to display the details. Definetly we cannot suggest every client to install on their device . Is there any other alternative ?

This question might been repeated so please feel free to redirect to the wright topic / thread.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated

Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the link https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3333000?hl=en we can refer serial number (s/n) for devices without call facility . I did try a sample it did work :-)

Happy Coding !!!